# Use psycopg in pass parameter of type geography(MultiPolygon, 4326)[] to PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, multi-polygon, psycopg2

I am using PostgreSQL + PostGIS to save a country border.

Following is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    name VARCHAR(256),
    description TEXT,
    geog geography(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326) NULL,
    flag VARCHAR(512) NULL,
    start_time TIMESTAMP,
    end_time TIMESTAMP,
    created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

And I defined following function to insert or update countries:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_countries (
        country_ids UUID [],
        country_names VARCHAR(256) [],
        country_descriptions TEXT [],
        country_geogs geography(MULTIPOLYGON, 4326) [],
        country_flags VARCHAR(512) [],
        country_start_times TIMESTAMP [],
        country_end_times TIMESTAMP []
    ) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE data RECORD;
BEGIN FOR data IN
SELECT *
FROM unnest(
        country_ids,
        country_names,
        country_descriptions,
        country_geogs,
        country_flags,
        country_start_times,
        country_end_times
    ) AS t(
        country_id,
        country_name,
        country_description,
        country_geog,
        country_flag,
        country_start_time,
        country_end_time
    ) LOOP
INSERT INTO country (
        id,
        name,
        description,
        geog,
        flag,
        start_time,
        end_time
    )
VALUEs (
        data.country_id,
        data.country_name,
        data.country_description,
        data.country_geog,
        data.country_flag,
        data.country_start_time,
        data.country_end_time
    ) ON CONFLICT (id) DO
UPDATE
SET name = data.country_name,
    description = data.country_description,
    geog = data.country_geog,
    flag = data.country_flag,
    start_time = data.country_start_time,
    end_time = data.country_end_time;
END LOOP;
END $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

In python code, I use following code to call function upsert_countries.

```
country_ids = [UUID('bddb20cc-5af0-4c46-b098-64b0f10321ab'), UUID('0c230e00-2e0d-472c-b136-8aa3410842b1')]
country_names = ['Rome Republic', 'Imperial Rome']
country_descriptions = ['Rome Republic', 'Imperial Rome']
country_geogs = ['MULTIPOLYGON (((1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1, 1 5)), ((6 5, 9 1, 6 1, 6 5)))', 'MULTIPOLYGON (((1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1, 1 5)), ((6 5, 9 1, 6 1, 6 5)))']
country_flags = [None, None]
country_start_times = ['510-01-01 BC', '31-01-01 BC']
country_end_times = ['31-01-01 BC', '476-01-01']
async with self.pool.connection() as conn:
    cur = await conn.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM upsert_countries(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);",
        (
            country_ids,
            country_names,
            country_descriptions,
            country_geogs,
            country_flags,
            country_start_times,
            country_end_times,
        ),
    )
        return await cur.fetchone()
```

But the above code didn't work, it raise error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg/connection_async.py", line 285, in execute
> raise ex.with_traceback(None)
> psycopg.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: "{"MULTIPOLYGON (((1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1, 1 5)), ((6 5, 9 1, 6 1, 6 5)))","MULTIPOLYGON (((1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1, 1 5)), ((6 5, 9 1, 6 1, 6 5)))"}"
> DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
> CONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $4 = '...'

How can I pass correct multipolygon to PostgreSQL function?

Comment: That's...an odd way to `INSERT`. Not sure if `psycopg` has any limitations here, but using a pool and running parallel `INSERT`s, or a multi-value `INSERT` even, would be much more performant. And idiomatic. And less error prone. Here I assume you need to change the function parameter type to `country_geog TEXT[]` and either let PG auto-cast to `GEOGRAPHY`, or add an explicit cast there.

Comment: I've gotten better performance inserting WKT text to a column with an ON INSERT TRIGGER to set the geometry/geography column contents (or leave it in the WKT on error) than inserting to a geometry directly with a geometry-aware interface, so this is a good route for a geometry-unaware interface.